# Many packages that should be available in Debian are not

Tags: linux, debian

There are many packages that are listed on the Debian site as being included in the repositories and fully supported by Debian, but when I try 'apt-get install' I am told: E: Unable to locate package. They also do not exist in synaptic.

Specifically, I am trying to install remmina (which should be simple), but has consumed several hours from my day. There seems to be no info on this. As I installed Debian with only DVD 1, I am assuming I need to download the references to most of the packages somewhere, but cannot find where or how to go.

I wanted to post a view of my sources list, but there are all kinds of formatting rules that I must follow, and then I am told I need x reputation points to post links (many addresses in sources.list). Basically I have main, contirb, and non-free enabled.

Thanks

Comment: Have you updated you package cache (apt-get update) ?

Comment: This should go to either Super User or Unix & Linux instead of SO as it's not related to programming.

Comment: Freud Chicken, yes I updated and upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

If a package is available on repository, then it should be available to you too.

1. Check name of the package with `apt-cache search <packagename>` or `aptitude search <packagename>` ( I do prefer `aptitude` to search packages ).
2. Double check if the desired component is enabled at your sources.list file and under `sources.list.d/`. Many people forget to enable the famous `contrib` and `non-free` components. Check which component is related to your package and update your sources.list.

I found these .deb files:

http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/remmina/remmina_1.0.0-4+deb7u1_amd64.deb
http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/remmina/remmina-common_1.0.0-4+deb7u1_all.deb

As you can see, according to [sources.list documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList) these files are under the **main** component.